# Angular Material form scrolls down on page load

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I created a long form using [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/).  Weird thing is that instead of the page displaying normally it starts off midway through the form.
Is this something my browser is doing (Perhaps it thinks I left off at a certain point last time)?

Not sure how to force the page to load normally and start from the top.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to track down the issue and it was the md-autocomplete field causing the page to scroll down.  To fix this I added md-autofocus="false" in the md-autocomplete field and now it loads normally.